# Puppet best practice for storing scripts for custom modules

Tags: puppet

I have Windows agent nodes. I am creating my own module which has some custom powershell scripts. I am wondering where should i be keeping these powershell scripts. Within my module itself in some folder (say, `scripts` dir) or somewhere outside my module's directory? What's the recommended/best practice in such scenario?

```
git/
    - client
        - hieradata
        - manifests
        - modules
            - my_module
                - scripts/ # 1) Should it be within this dir?
                    - my_script.ps1
        - scripts/         # 2) Should it be within this dir or elsewhere?      
            - my_script.ps1 
        - templates
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A [module can ship with its own files and templates](https://docs.puppet.com/puppet/4.9/modules_fundamentals.html#example):

```
[modules_root]
    my_module
        files
            my_script
        manifests
            init.pp
        templates
            other_script.erb
```

As OPs post suggests installing templates out of the modules scope, ... I feel it is necessary to also note that we would install these with:

```
file {
    "/etc/toto":
        source => "puppet:///modules/my_module/my_script";
    "/etc/tata":
        content => template("my_module/other_script.erb");
}
```

Comment: OP is asking where to put his scripts files, not how to ship some scripts with puppet.

Comment: @Tolsadus this is exactly what the first snippet explains. I added the second one, as the source/content values do depend on the layout described in the first block.

Answer (score 0):

**Modules are self-contained bundles of code and data. You can download pre-built modules from the Puppet Forge or you can write your own modules.**

According to the [official documentation](https://docs.puppet.com/puppet/4.9/modules_fundamentals.html), there isn't any "good" practice where to put your personal scripts for a custom module.

However, the folder `files` can **contain Contains static files, which managed nodes can download** which is the closest place to put some personal scripts.

You could also create a *script* folder, if you believe it's clear enough for others people to read, and understand your module.

```
 On disk, a module is simply a directory tree with a specific, predictable structure:

 - manifests
 - files
 - templates
 - lib
 - facts.d
 - examples
 - spec
 - functions
 - types
```

In term of more general best practice, I would recommend you to read [this](https://devops.com/puppet-best-practices/).

Comment: Thanks for the links. I had already gone through both those links before and yes, you're right that there's no suggestion about the _right_ place to put custom scripts.

Answer (score 0):

The only place you should be storing those scripts is in the module's `files` directory.

You can then deploy the script using the `source` parameter of the `file` resource like so:

```
file {'myfile':
  ensure => file,
  source => 'puppet:///modules/mymodule/myfile',
}
```